# How to solve $x = 45 \cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve the equation $x = 45 \cos(x)$?

I have tried online graphing charts (e.g. desmos) and online calculators (e.g. wolframalpha) to find the root of the above equation. I am getting multiple solutions for the given equation and below is the partial list:

- 44.174
- 43.745
- 38.254
- 37.097

The problem is that, when I plug in these values in the given equation, these values don't satisfy it.

Comment: $$45\cos(44.174)\approx44.175,\\45\cos(37.097)\approx37.086$$ so what ?

Comment: As, the cosine function is periodic, it is possible that there is more than one root. Also ensure that you enter the value of $x$ in **radians**.

Comment: What do you mean by "these values don't satisfy it"?  They clearly do.  Recall all trig functions are in *radians* unless specified otherwise.

Comment: I am so sorry. I forgot to mention that I am looking for the solution in degrees and not radians.

Comment: but you cannot find answers in degrees because the left hand side is a real number

Answer (score 1):

Please note that all these solutions are in **radians**.

Answer (score 0):

When you tried the graphing approach, what did it look like?
For my Desmos graph I plotted the left and right sides of your equation as separate functions, that is, one function was plotted by 
$y = x$ and the other by $y = 45 \cos(x).$
My graph looked like this:

[image]

Notice that the cosine function on this graph goes through multiple cycles 
between $x = 0$ and $x = 20.$
That's because if you want the input value of the mathematical cosine function
to represent an angle, you have to measure that angle in radians,
as several other people have already pointed out.

If you are thinking of the "cosine" function that takes the number of *degrees* in an angle and produces a sinusoidal function $f$ that decreases from 
$f(0)=1$ to $f(90) = 0,$
you can tell Desmos to plot $y=\cos\left(\frac\pi{180}x\right),$
or you can go into its settings and select "Degrees" instead of "Radians".
Making either of these changes, I get a graph like this:
[image]

Comment: for me the graph looked like the first graph. I was not aware that the default settings in desmos were in radians. After converting radians to degrees, now my graph looks like latter one which has only one solution. Thanks for pointing it out.